# My Mouse is Too Fast on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, settings

I just installed 12.04 but the mouse is far too fast and it is almost
impossible to do a double click. I have checked the mouse speed settings with no success.

Comment: Checkout this link: http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/

Comment: @kingmilo Thanks for the link, I'd have upvoted it if it were an answer! (And still will.)

Comment: @Ringtail This is to do with tracking speed (and clicking speed), not scroll speed.

Comment: @Sparhawk - thanks for the feedback ;) added as answer, always happy for an upvote!

Answer (score 4):

Checkout this link: http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/

Have fun!

Comment: I did upvote, but you probably should copy-paste from the page, just in case the link dies.

Answer (score 1):

All settings concerning your mouse (speed, acceleration, double-click speed ...) can be found in Settings > Mouse. In this case, slide the bars under "Pointer speed" for acceleration and sensitivity.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Some mice have their own speed settings separate from the OS, for example, I had a mouse that had a button that would let you adjust the sensitivity there. Check and see if your mouse has any of those.